# Substring in Java

Tags: java

I have a string in format `/remove_this/I_want_this_onward/any_number_of_characters`.
I want to remove `/remove_this` and want to get remaining string i.e. `/I_want_this_onward/any_number_of_characters`.
Ex. Input String `/myApp/home/welcome` , I want to extract `/home/welcome`.
What will be the the easiest way in Java to get it done ?

**EDIT:** (extracted from comments)

I want it to extract `/home/welcome` from `redirect:/myapp/home/welcome`.

Comment: I tried substring and normal for loop.

Comment: Substring should do the trick, see Daniels answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your comment in Daniel's answer is the last word, I'm guessing you wish to find the second forward slash, and copy the remaining characters.

Here's my attempt.

```
int pos = s.indexOf("/");
s.substring(s.indexOf("/", pos+1));
```

if you wish to find the third forward slash, you'd add the following line in between the two lines of code above:

```
pos = s.indexOf("/", pos+1);
```

if you wish to find the fourth, fifth, sixth, etc. forward slash, you would put the above statement in a `WHILE` loop, in between the two lines of code above.

Answer (score 7):

That would be

```
s.substring(s.indexOf("/",1))
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didnt work for string like "redirect:/myapp/home/welcome"

Comment: Now you are adding stripping "redirect:/myapp"?  Thats different than your question suggests.  Using substring as suggested answers your question.

Comment: @Peter: I came across this input later. Sorry I assumed it while putting this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 yourString.replace(aOldPattern, aNewPattern);
```

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=80

This is assuming  you know what the string is you want to replace each time.  If you don't, you can use:

```
 yourString.split("/"); // if you know the delimiter is always `/`
```

From that, you can then omit the first instance from the split and print out the rest...